# How to upload a table with a R shiny app in two different excluding processes using the same variable name

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed a quite complex Shiny app that helps the user filter an uploaded table of genetics variants. So that, the user can upload a table, apply different filters and see the variants remaining. Now I would like the user to be able to upload the table in two different and excluding ways:

First: the table is straightaway uploaded by the user with fileInput.
Second: the user presses a button that makes the table being applied a series of changes with a python program that works outside shiny, then a processed table is created for the session and uploaded for filtering with another button.

Both options result in an uploaded table that can be filtered with my program, so I would like to conserve same the variable name in both cases. Both processes work perfectly when the other is commented, however I would like to have both uploading options available for the user. Due to the complexity of the program I cannot show a totally reproducible example here, but I can show you the part of the code I want to work in.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)    
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyFiles)

ui = fluidPage(

# Uploading variant table straight away with a file input (way 1):
fileInput("file1", "Upload your SNV File",
            multiple = FALSE,
            accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".tsv")),

# User presses a button if changes previous to the upload want to be applied (way 2):
actionBttn(
    inputId = "WGS",
    label = "Analysis of WGS", 
),

# User needs to fill a survey before the python program is launched:
bsModal("survey", "Select WGS data information","WGS", 
        prettyCheckbox(inputId="canonical_filters", label = "Canonical", value = TRUE),
        shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Process WGS variant file", title = "WGS variant file:", multiple = FALSE),
        actionButton("EnterWGS", "Read file")),

# Table is rendered
DTOutput("contents")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

# Datatable is uploaded straight away (WAY 1)
df <- reactive({
      req(input$file1)
      df <- read.table(input$file1$datapath, fill = TRUE, quote = "", header = TRUE,
                       sep = '\t', na.strings=c("",".","NA"), colClasses = NA)
    
  })

# The path of the file where the changes are going to be applied can be selected and the python program (process_file.py) is launched with the system function. A processed variant table is created for the session.
observeEvent(input$Btn_GetFile, {  
    volumes = getVolumes()
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots=volumes, session = session, filetypes = c('', 'txt',  "tsv", "csv"))
    file_selected<-parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
    if (length(file_selected$datapath)!=0){
        system('process_file.py', file_selected$datapath )
      }
  })
  

# The processed variant table is uploaded when the button is pressed (WAY 2)  
df <- eventReactive(input$EnterWGS, {
    df <- read.table('temp_file', fill = TRUE, quote = "", header = TRUE,
                     sep = '\t', na.strings=c("",".","NA"), check.names = FALSE, colClasses = NA)
  }, ignoreNULL = T)


# Rest of the functions...

# Table renderization.
  output$contents <- renderDT({
    req(df())
    datatable(
      df(),
      filter = "top", 
      class = "display nowrap compact",
      escape = FALSE)},
    server = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I really hope this is understandable. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Rachael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `reactiveValues` object to display which is set to table 1 or table 2.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)    
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyFiles)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  # Uploading variant table straight away with a file input (way 1):
  fileInput("file1", "Upload your SNV File",
            multiple = FALSE,
            accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".tsv")),
  
  # User presses a button if changes previous to the upload want to be applied (way 2):
  actionBttn(
    inputId = "WGS",
    label = "Analysis of WGS", 
  ),
  
  # User needs to fill a survey before the python program is launched:
  bsModal("survey", "Select WGS data information","WGS", 
          prettyCheckbox(inputId="canonical_filters", label = "Canonical", value = TRUE),
          shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Process WGS variant file", title = "WGS variant file:", multiple = FALSE),
          actionButton("EnterWGS", "Read file")),
  
  # Table is rendered
  DTOutput("contents")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(df=NULL)
  # Datatable is uploaded straight away (WAY 1)
  df1 <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    df <- read.table(input$file1$datapath, fill = TRUE, quote = "", header = TRUE,
                     sep = '\t', na.strings=c("",".","NA"), colClasses = NA)
    
  })
  
  # The path of the file where the changes are going to be applied can be selected and the python program (process_file.py) is launched with the system function. A processed variant table is created for the session.
  observeEvent(input$Btn_GetFile, {  
    volumes = getVolumes()
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots=volumes, session = session, filetypes = c('', 'txt',  "tsv", "csv"))
    file_selected<-parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
    if (length(file_selected$datapath)!=0){
      system('process_file.py', file_selected$datapath )
    }
  })
  
  
  # The processed variant table is uploaded when the button is pressed (WAY 2)  
  df2 <- eventReactive(input$EnterWGS, {
    df <- read.table('temp_file', fill = TRUE, quote = "", header = TRUE,
                     sep = '\t', na.strings=c("",".","NA"), check.names = FALSE, colClasses = NA)
  }, ignoreNULL = T)
  
  ###  condition this observer to display df1()
  observeEvent(df1(), {
    rv$df <- df1()
  })
  
  ###  condition this observer to display df2()
  observeEvent(input$WGS, {
    rv$df <- df2()
  })
  
  # Rest of the functions...
  
  # Table renderization.
  output$contents <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      rv$df,
      filter = "top", 
      class = "display nowrap compact",
      escape = FALSE)},
    server = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```